# Copy Paste from Central Repository is Weird

Tags: java, maven

This question is a bit odd -- so bear with me.  If this is the wrong site to ask this question, please kindly advise the correct Stack site.

I use the website http://search.maven.org to find Java dependencies for my Maven-based projects.

[Take this artefact as an example](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccglib%7Ccglib-nodep%7C2.1_3%7Cjar).

In the Dependency Information box (for Apache Maven), double click to highlight all text, then copy-paste into your favourite text editor.  Look at the raw bytes.  Something is weird.  If I paste directly into my `pom.xml` file, Maven cries foul during the `validate` stage about badly formatted XML.

[image]

Example raw text with octal literals:

```
<dependency>
\302\240\302\240\302\240\302\240<groupId>cglib</groupId>
\302\240\302\240\302\240\302\240<artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
\302\240\302\240\302\240\302\240<version>2.1_3</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I crazy or does anyone else have this issue?  Is this a problem with my web browser (Chrome), my text editor (Notepad++), my operating system (Windows 7) or the Central Repo website?

**Update**

- I tried copying from Google Chrome and pasting into various places.  All have the same issue.  I even tried pasting into a Cygwin session running vim.  Same issue.
- I tried with Internet Explorer 9 and the text has regular whitespace (\040).

This looks like an encoding issue with either The Central Repo website, or my browser, Google Chrome.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  Perhaps your environment doesn't like the non-breaking spaces?

Answer (score 3):

If seems there is some conversion between unicode and and ASCII.

"\302\240" is a whitespace in unicode and I guess you paste it to an ANSI document and somewhere some conversion kicks in.

I can't reproduce it with Maxthon, so I guess it is an issue with Chrome or something else interferring with the pasting (like Notepad++ plugins maybe).

Comment: Likely also very platform-dependent. The editor, the browser, and the OS probably all play into it.